# Getting a table data from an old Database

Tags: sql, vb.net, sql-server-ce

A while back, I made and published software with an sdf database. Now I want to improve it and add more features: new forms and new tables in the database. How can I get the data stored in a table (where the table is still has the same proprieties in my new database) and added them to my new database?

Answer (score 0):

Typically, the way to approach this problem is not to move the data to a new database, but rather use the SQL `ALTER` statement to add or remove the columns you need from the old database in place. The installer for the new program needs to be smart enough to detect the old database file, and you write code for the installer (or a check when the program starts up) that is able to handle the upgrade process.

This works especially well if you are doing source control correctly. With source control, you have to commit or check in changes for the code, but it's no good committing a change that needs the database to have a column that's not yet available. Thus a good source control environment encourages you to write the `ALTER` statement to add that column as part of the rest of the feature work. Someone else needs a different column on the same table? They write their own `ALTER` statement. Later, their branch can merged with yours, but the database still ends up exactly as it needs to be. Moreover, these commits to the database project can then be collected and used for the upgrade process when you are ready to publish the application.

Comment: but i already created a new project , how to get old data from old database ?